# Unicode character-specific CSS - a thought

Tags: css, unicode

As a native Bānglā (Language: Bengali) writer, we are dependent on to Unicode Bānglā characters. As we all know Unicode is an extended version of ASCII, and all the ASCII characters are still preserved in Unicode. And the rest of the World glyphs were added then. Now in Bānglā and other languages' concern (it can be Chinese, Hebrew, Japanese or Javanese), we have glyphs on Unicode.

But in Bānglā's concern the `font-size: 100%` for English characters is not enough for Bānglā characters. Because of the glyphs' position inside every grid. The thing can be understood by the following image:

[image: Bānglā and English glyphs in grid]

While English character is largely fit in a grid, the Bānglā character is shrinked to fit within because of other supporting vowel-sign-glyphs.

Hence, while we put `body{font-size: 100%}` it's nice for English glyphs, but with the same CSS shows the Bānglā fonts smaller.

**SOLUTION, NOW**
At present, how we do solution for that, is to choose a nice font that has both good English and Bānglā glyphs, i.e. "Siyam Rupali". So that, it solves the matter a very little.

#### NEW THOUGHT

But what I'm thinking is a bit new:
» **Why not we target the Unicode glyphs and put some specific CSS for only those?**

*Suppose* the Unicode serial number `#0048 4614 5784 4578` represents the first Bānglā character and `#0048 4614 5784 9999` represents the last. So, if we can do some CSS like:

```
Unicode[glyph="0048461457844578" - "0048461457849999"]{
   font-size: 150%;
}
```

**I know nothing like the above is present in CSS.** But, is there a way we can target specific glyphs to pose different CSS styles onto 'em?

If there's a way then many of the Bānglā Unicode users will be benefited, especially a large portion of Online Bānglā Newspapers need such a tweak over content to achieve dynamic control.

Comment: `<span class="bangla">.....</span>` and apply CSS accordingly. Or, if Bānglā is prevalent, style for it and use `<span class="latin">abc</span>` as needed.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What if the texts come from a WYSIWYG Editor and my front-end `<div>` simply hold 'em all at once? How can I target a specific content portion to load a `<span>` to hold that portion in?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Using the `lang` attribute would make more sense semantically – and is enough to target the element via CSS in modern browsers, so the class can be omitted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is entirely a problem of fonts. If you choose a well balanced font in which glyph sizes are adjusted in a way that mixed language text looks good together, there's no real problem. CSS can help you here in so far as you can specify custom fonts for certain characters using [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face):

```
@font-face {
  font-family:   'bangla';
  src:           url('http://example.com/mybangla.ttf');
  unicode-range: U+0980-09FF;
}
```

This fictional "bangla" font now applies only to the Unicode range U+0980 - U+09FF, which is the Bengali block. Choose some fonts wisely and you can create a well balanced appearance in modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems a good solution to that. With your clue/complete answer, I found [this article](http://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/) helpful describing this. Thanks again.