# Is it possible to check browser's default font setup using PHP?

Tags: php, css, unicode, font-face

[As per my Question regarding Unicode Character-specific CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464725/unicode-character-specific-css-a-thought), I got a good solution: `unicode-range`, but in reality it's not actually working, or it's working without any visible changes.

And I followed the [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax Tutorial](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) by Paul Irish for indexing my embeddable fonts. It's somehow embedding fonts, but not correctly (**My problem is specific to Bānglā fonts**). If I set up the font in my browser, then it's giving the perfect size and glyph view of the font. But if I delete the specific font from `/windows/fonts` folder, then the embed is NOT showing the texts in correct sizes. So the actual `font-size` property is my problem.

If I can detect whether the Bānglā font is default in the browser then I'll load smaller fonts, if not then I'll load a bigger.

So, **is it really possible to detect which is the Default Font enabled in a browser?**

#### EDIT

My live site is [dev.nanodesignsbd.com](http://dev.nanodesignsbd.com) - if that could help somebody to find a bug in @font-face bulletproof syntax. And the attached image will talk for me:
[image: what I want my fonts]

And that can only be done with a browser font setup. :(

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not on the browser. So, no, you can't determine the font using PHP alone. You need JavaScript for that.

Comment: @AmalMurali that should be an answer instead ;)

Comment: @AmalMurali, how would you use JavaScript for this? I don’t think you can. So I think the correct answer is just “You can’t”.

Comment: I doubt there's a reliable way to do this in Javascript, either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check what fonts are installed on machines via the web?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945644/is-there-a-way-to-check-what-fonts-are-installed-on-machines-via-the-web)

Comment: It seems that the *real* problem is quite different from the one asked.

Comment: I edited my Question with some more details. And @AmalMurali answering a question isn't the thing but trying to provide solution to the problem is. That what exactly an answer by Matthew R. Thanks to him. But I edited with some more details if there's something I need to fix in my CSS...

Comment: @MayeenulIslam: I didn't say it is not possible. I just said it's not possible to **reliably** determine the font.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is a server-side language and runs on the web server. It has no control over the user's web browser and can't really determine the font (or anything else, for that matter). For dealing with client-side stuff, you'll need JavaScript. That said, I don't think it's possible to reliably determine the font using JavaScript, either.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the default font is placed on the `<body>` or `<html>` tags with CSS. These are defined by default in the browsers configuration. The only was to get the default for a specified browser in PHP would be to see what the defaults are for each browser and each language you want to support. You would then have to parse the user agent string to see which default *should* be in place.

**The best solution would not be in PHP** since, as I said, the browsers define these fonts in CSS. Rather, you can use javascript to check what the default font is after the page has loaded.

You can do this with `getComputedStyle()` like so:

**FOR HTML TAG**

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body.parentNode);
```

**FOR BODY TAG**

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
```

These will return an array of the computed styles for the browser.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

PHP will let you get some information about the browser. None of the information is regarding font.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

I think this is the most platform specific information you'll get:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);

Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the original question that was asked.

Comment: Sure it does.  This is the information about the client that you can get.  Notice that font isn't included, therefore the answer is you can't.