# Is there any working @font-face for Bengali (Bānglā) language?

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, font-face

I'm struggling to embed Bengali (Bānglā) Unicode fonts into my website for a couple of days and I tried many things. Even I got some wonderful solutions for `@font-face` like `unicode-range` ([see deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19465022/1743124)). I even tried the so-called [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax Tutorial by Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/). But finally found that the font embed looks working, but actually not working at all. If I delete the Bānglā font from the PC (`/windows/fonts`), then my browser fails to load the font from the system, and it's not working. What I'm using for `@font-face` is:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Siyam Rupali';
  src: url('fonts/siyamrupali-webfont.eot');
  src: url('fonts/siyamrupali-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  src: local('Siyam Rupali Regular'), local('Siyam Rupali'),
  url('fonts/siyamrupali-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/siyamrupali-webfont.otf') format('opentype'),
  url('fonts/siyamrupali-webfont.svg#siyam_rupaliregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  unicode-range: U+0980-09FF; //Bengali Range (source: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf‎‎)
}
```

And regardless to say that I downloaded the `Siyam Rupali` font from the web (forgot the source I'm afraid), then made the webfonts using FontSquirrel's @font-face generator.

And I called the font as:

```
body{
   font-family: "Siyam Rupali", Cambria, sans-serif;
}
```

**Result:** Not Working!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After long challenging research, I failed. But suddenly I remember my den in [Bengali (Bānglā) Wikipedia](http://bn.wikipedia.org), wherewith the help of Jayanthanath, we the community embedded "Siyam Rupali" into Bengali (Bānglā) Wikipedia. The discussion can be found [here in this Village Pump discussion archive](https://bn.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A6%89%E0%A6%87%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%B2%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%9A%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%BE/%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%B9%E0%A6%B6%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE/%E0%A7%A8%E0%A7%A6%E0%A7%A7%E0%A7%A8/%E0%A7%A7-%E0%A7%AA#%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AE_%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%BC%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%AC_%E0%A6%AB%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%9F_-%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE_%E0%A6%89%E0%A6%87%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%BC). Then I got an Idea and observe the font-embeds' success result in bn.wiki. Then using Firefox's "Web Developer" add-on, I viewed the whole bunch of CSS of Bengali (Bānglā) Wikipedia home page. And found 'Siyam Rupali' there. Then copied the syntax exactly from there:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Siyam Rupali';
    src: url('https://bits.wikimedia.org/static-current/extensions/UniversalLanguageSelector/data/fontrepo/fonts/SiyamRupali/SiyamRupali.eot?version=1.070');
    src: local('Siyam Rupali'),     url('https://bits.wikimedia.org/static-current/extensions/UniversalLanguageSelector/data/fontrepo/fonts/SiyamRupali/SiyamRupali.woff?version=1.070') format('woff'),        url('https://bits.wikimedia.org/static-current/extensions/UniversalLanguageSelector/data/fontrepo/fonts/SiyamRupali/SiyamRupali.ttf?version=1.070') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;}
```

I then implemented my CSS accordingly. But still having issues. Then I copied the path of the files used in bn.wiki:

- SiyamRupali.eot — ([Wikimedia path](https://bits.wikimedia.org/static-current/extensions/UniversalLanguageSelector/data/fontrepo/fonts/SiyamRupali/SiyamRupali.eot))
- SiyamRupali.woff — ([Wikimedia path](https://bits.wikimedia.org/static-current/extensions/UniversalLanguageSelector/data/fontrepo/fonts/SiyamRupali/SiyamRupali.woff))
- SiyamRupali.ttf — ([Wikimedia path](https://bits.wikimedia.org/static-current/extensions/UniversalLanguageSelector/data/fontrepo/fonts/SiyamRupali/SiyamRupali.ttf))

and downloaded the exact font. And after that, I found some unwanted mismatches in sizes, with the version of the font I had.

```
+=====================+====================+
| PREVIOUS FILE SIZES | BN.WIKI FILE SIZES |
+=====================+====================+
|      EOT : 23KB     |    EOT : 144KB     |
|      TTF : 47KB     |    TTF : 392KB     |
|     WOFF : 26KB     |    WOFF : 166KB    |
|      SVG : 71KB     |     [NO SVG]       |
+=====================+====================+
```

I thought that can make some difference in proper glyphs. So simply replaced my fonts with the newly downloaded versions. And with my final bit of code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Siyam Rupali';
  src: url('fonts/SiyamRupali.eot?version=1.070');
  src: local('Siyam Rupali'), url('fonts/SiyamRupali.woff?version=1.070') format('woff'),       url('fonts/SiyamRupali.ttf?version=1.070') format('truetype');
  font-style: normal;
  unicode-range: U+0980-09FF; //Bangla Range (source: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf‎‎)
}
```

It simply works like a charm! I'm not concerned about IE6, because even with the bulletproof, it's dumb! :( I tested Firefox 20.0, Opera 10.10, and Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m.

The font Siyam Rupali is now available over the developer community:

- [Siyam Rupali - GitHub.com](https://github.com/potasiyam/Siyam-Rupali)

Thanks to Tanbin Islam Siyam (the *Potasiyam*) for his wonderful font: Siyam Rupali.

And also the following list can provide a good overview of the present condition of the improvement of Bengali (Bānglā) Unicode availability:

- [Language Support Status - Indic Language Support: MediaWiki.org](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Language_tools/Requirements/Indic_language_support#Language_support_status)

#### EDIT

I found `unicode-range:` causing a problem in Chrome. As Siyam Rupali is a very good font with a vast collection of glyphs, we need not mention the range. So, you *can* avoid `unicode-range: U+0980-09FF;`. :)

### Update 2019

`unicode-range` is well supported now. You can check the [Can I use Status](https://caniuse.com/?search=unicode-range)

Comment: Hard work always paid off. But now I am have font issue :(